# speech recognition: what to do, when i speak "write", but the recognition is "right". an App, written in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, speech-recognition

I write an App in Kotlin. I use the standard speechrecognition with

```
fun fbtnhear(view: View) {
    val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, inputspeech) //"de_DE")   //en_US")  ??// de_DE?
    //intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.US.toString())
    //intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault())
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Du bist dran")
    startActivityForResult(intent, sPEECHINTENTRQ)
}
```

with onActivitiyResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
if (requestCode == sPEECHINTENTRQ && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    val speechresult2: ArrayList<String> =
            data?.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS) ?: ArrayList()
    if (speechresult2.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    } else {

        speechlist.clear()
        speechresult2.forEach() {
            speechlist.add(it)
        }
```

You know, there are words, which sound  the same, but are written different. A simple example is "write" and "right". I hoped, that the  "val speechresult2 = ArrayList" would give me a list of possible words to give me a chance for a spinner or so to select the word, that i meant.

Unfortunatly I only get one (1) response.

Why does the arraylist not deliver several possible results?

Doesn't it work that way or did I miss something? (I studied a lot of documentation and questions here, but didn't find an answer)

Answer (score 0):

isn't "write" pronounced "right"? Because that might be why...

Comment: P.S. "right" is pronounced "write", so just check if it's "right" and then, if is, ask them 'write' or 'right'

Comment: i hope to get as an answer  from the speechrecognition  a list "write" or "right", give it to a selector like a spinner to be able to select, what i meant.

Comment: well, just make a spinner and make two choices: write and right and if any: let the user select between right and write and, for others just make the same like: to and too and two

Comment: sorry NO. write and right is only an example. I speak any word into the speechrecognizer. A lot of the words are recognized correctly. But there are some words, the recognizer can't decide, see EXAMPLE write and right. And then I hope to get a list of words, which could match to the spoken text. The result of the recognizer is an ArrayList. Why doesn't  it give me the alternative writings?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found the solution!
I have to add

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3)
```

in my funktion fun btnhear. This allows the app to give a list of possible solutions. I think that the default value is 1. (I didn't find it in documentation. But checking some additional threads here I found this parameter in an example, testet it and it worked as I hoped. ) My parameter 3 here is only an example, too!

Thanks to all. I will close the question in a few days